# Ruby on rails CSRF protection forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf, owasp

I understand that rails add CSRF tokens to the forms created with its custom functions like form_with etc. BUT does it also generate CSRF tokens (a.k.a authenticity_token in rails terms) for general HTML

I am seeing mixed answers for this. Anyone with hands-on experience on Rails help me here?

Comment: Are you asking if you manually create a `<form></form>` without using a Rails helper method, will it automatically add the authenticity token? No, it will not.

Comment: Yes, thats my question. Are you sure about it? [1] says it does but some other articles I read says they don't. 

[1] https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/11/per-form-csrf-token-in-rails-5.html

Comment: I'm positive. In a Rails 5 app, on a blank page using HAML with a single tag `%form` the output rendered is `<html><head></head><body><form></form></body></html>`. No auth token. Note that in your linked article it says "A typical form _generated_ in Rails..." meaning generated using a [Rails form helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I should make this into a full fledged answer.

No, manually creating a `<form></form>` in Rails will not automatically insert the authenticity token. The token is only inserted when using a [Rails form helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). These helpers allow you to specify the fields for a form without specifying the authenticity token; it will put the token field into the form automatically. For example:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />

  <%= f.label :last_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Generates the following HTML with the hidden `authenticity_token` field:

```
<form action="/people" class="new_person" id="new_person" method="post">
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="NrOp5bsjoLRuK8IW5+dQEYjKGUJDe7TQoZVvq95Wteg=" />
  <label for="person_first_name">First name</label>:
  <input id="person_first_name" name="person[first_name]" type="text" /><br />

  <label for="person_last_name">Last name</label>:
  <input id="person_last_name" name="person[last_name]" type="text" /><br />

  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Person" />
</form>
```

But if you manually generate the HTML, for example using [HAML](http://haml.info):

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    %form
```

The generated HTML looks like:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

...without any `authenticity_token` field.

In [the article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/11/per-form-csrf-token-in-rails-5.html) you linked to, it says "A typical form *generated* in Rails..." meaning generated using a Rails form helper. Manually created forms are not "generated" in the sense used in this context.

Comment: Thank you..It answers my question. Accepted it.